# Deployment error when defining a security-domain

Tags: java-ee-7, wildfly-8

I am working on a JavaEE7 tutorial ; currently I am trying to establish a security domain using wildfly 8.2.0. These are the settings I use:

jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
<security-domain>my-aktion</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

The part of standalone.xml that handles this security-domain:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
    <security-domains>              
        <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
                <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
            <authorization>
                <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
            <authorization>
                <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="my-aktion" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/MyAktionDS"/>
                    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from organizer where email=?"/>
                    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select 'Organizer','Roles' from organizer where email=?"/>
                    <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256" />
                    <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex" />
                    <module-option name="hashCharset" value="UTF-8" />
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
    </security-domains>
</subsystem>
```

And that´s the error I get when I try to deploy:

```
> "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>     "jboss.deployment.unit.\"my-aktion.war\".component.DonationServiceBean.CREATE
> is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.my-aktion]",
>     "jboss.deployment.unit.\"my-aktion.war\".component.CampaignServiceBean.CREATE
> is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.my-aktion]",
>     "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./my-aktion.UndertowDeploymentInfoService
> is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.my-aktion]" ]}
```

I can´t make heads or tails from this error message, but it seems to be something I did wrong with the my-aktion security domain, maybe someone has a hint. In any case, I tried deleting jboss-web.xml, the application deploys fine, but I can´t login, probably because the querys handling the login are in the "my-aktion" security-domain. Probably a newbie error here, but I just can´t find it.

EDIT: By the way, just in case it matters: the two Beans mentioned in the error are annotated @Stateless and I have no beans.xml.

EDIT2: I solved the problem, but I still don´t know what caused it. The solution: I deleted myaktion-ds.xml, which contained the registration of my datasource and moved its content to a  tag in my standalone.xml. Now everything works, although why it does is beyond me. 
I´ll leave this question here for a couple of days, just in case someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same tutorial and had the same problem. It tookt me houres, but i finaly found a solution that worked for me:

It seems that the deployment process triggert by my IDE (netbeans) is configurated by the standalone-**full**.xml and not by standalone.xml. 
After editing the both xml-files every thing worked fine for me.